# Getting the last datum in a vega dataset

Tags: vega

I have a data source A and I'd like to create a new data source B containing just the last element of A. What is the best way to do this in Vega?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively straight forward to do. Although I am slightly confused by your use of "max" in the aggregation since this isn't the last value?

Either way here is my solution for obtaining the last value in a dataset using this series of transforms,

```
  transform: [
    {
      type: window
      ops: [
        row_number
      ]
    }
    {
      type: joinaggregate
      fields: [
        row_number
      ]
      ops: [
        max
      ]
      as: [
        max_row_number
      ]
    }
    {
      type: filter
      expr: datum.row_number==datum.max_row_number
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in the [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited) using the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source",
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega/master/docs/data/cars.json",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum['Horsepower'] != null && datum['Miles_per_Gallon'] != null && datum['Acceleration'] != null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "avg",
      "source":"source",
      "transform":[
        {
          "type":"aggregate",
          "groupby":["Horsepower"],
          "ops": ["average"],
          "fields":["Miles_per_Gallon"],
          "as":["Avg_Miles_per_Gallon"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"last",
      "source": "avg",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "ops": ["max"],
          "fields": ["Horsepower"],
          "as": ["maxHorsepower"]
        },
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "avg",
          "key": "Horsepower",
          "fields": ["maxHorsepower"],
          "values": ["Horsepower","Avg_Miles_per_Gallon"]
        }
      ]
    }   
  ]
}
```

| maxHorsepower | Horsepower | Avg_Miles_per_Gallon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 230 | 230 | 16 |

I'd be interested to know if there are better ways, but this worked for me.